Jammy 22.04 Attaching a pro subscription
when I try to attach my UbuntuPro subscription it keeps failing with no real error message.
lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS
Release:        22.04

Here is what I am running and the output I get:
root@REDACTED-REDACTED:~# pro attach C13dREDACTEDb
Failed to attach machine. See https://ubuntu.com/pro/dashboard

Has anybody else ran into this with some possible work around?  Do we know the source server name it is trying to hit some maybe I can set it to be able to get access for to that domain in case our firewall rules are blocking that domain?  This is a corporate firewall so things are pretty locked down.
Thanks!
Greg

Tell us more. Is it a desktop installation, a server, an IOT, or a cloud instance? Have you tried logging in as normal user and use sudo?

Yes I have tried as a normal user as well with the same result.  This is a server installation that will be running landscape on it.
